# drawViewHierarchyInRect is Crash on Iphone6 plus（Ios 8.2）

Tags: ios, iphone-6-plus, uigraphicscontext

```
class func imageWithView(view : UIView) -> UIImage {
    println(view.bounds.size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img
}
```

this function run in Iphone6-Plus will cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS on “drawViewHierarchyInRect”. in Iphone6-Plus simulator it capture empty image. 
but its fine on Iphone5 Iphone6...

Comment: try with afterScreenUpdates:false

Comment: yes I try it , but it do not work also